# Get track by its unique ID to remove it

Tags: java

> I am currently working on a train simulation project and I am having some trouble with the `delete track <ID>` command.
>
> Her is my execute() method for the command:

```
public void execute(List<String> args) throws BadSyntaxException {
    if (args.size() != 1) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid number of 
    arguments."); }

    int trackId = Integer.parseInt(args.get(0));

    register.removeTrack(*);
}
```

Now, I need to somehow get the Track to be removed by its unique ID for `*`.

Here is my constructor of Track.java:

```
public Track(int id, Point startPoint, Point endPoint) { ... }
```

And this is in the class where I register everything:

```
private List<Track> tracks;
private IdTracker trackIds;
```

**My solution approach so far:**

```
public Track getTrack(int id) {
    for (Track track : tracks) {
        if (track.getId() == id) {
            return track;
        }
    }
}
```

But what do I return if the track with the given ID doesn't exist? There is probably a more efficient way than doing it like this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You could either return null or an Optional.ofNullable(track).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return [`Optional<Track>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to signify that a track with given id might not exist:

```
public Optional<Track> getTrack(int id) {
  for (Track track : tracks) {
    if (track.getId() == id) {
      return Optional.of(track);
    }
  }
  return Optional.empty()
}
```

If you are concerned with efficiency you could explore using `Map<Integer, Track>` if each `Track` has a unique identifier. The question is if the speed up in track lookup is worth the cost of maintaining the map.

```
Map<Integer, Track> tracksById = ...

public Optional<Track> getTrack(int id) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(tracksById.get(id));
}
```